# Thin wire overheats, thick wire allows too much current to flow

Tags: motor, wire, overheat

I'm currently building a mini lathe to turn wood. I am using a 12v motor and I was experiencing some initial problems with the thin wires I was using; they overheated instantly.

I then changed to 14 AWG (thicker wire), and the motor was so strong this time that it hurled the wood straight out. I'm guessing this is due to it having less electrical resistance?

I was wondering if there was a solution to alleviate both issues. If the wire is too thin it overheats, while if it's too thick it overclocks the motor. Do I just have to keep buying wires until I find the sweet spot, or is there a better way?

Thanks! (I hope this was informative enough, I don't have much of an electrical background)

Comment: please provide some more detailed description or schematic of your setup. Where is this wire? the supply lead to the motor? are you trying to wind your own electrical machine? what are you actually doing? at any rate wires getting hot does not sound good. They are not designed to do that. PS If you don't have much electrical background please at least limit your experiments to 12V, and even then with some caution. You don't want an electrical fire on your hands.

Comment: "threw the wood out" is a chucking (workholding) issue. Fix that for safety's sake.

Comment: This is how strong the motor is *supposed* to be \*. Previously your wire was choking it so it couldn't go as fast as it was supposed to. Now you have no problem with the wire, the wire is doing just fine. You should investigate the motor instead. Maybe you can use gears, or a different motor, or reduce the voltage as the answer suggested. (\* probably)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thick wire is good, the low resistance gives you low losses.

If the torque of the motor is too high, reduce the voltage. Preferably you use a 12V source, that you can adjust to the value you want (that is basically what you are doing right now with the different wire resistance, but this results, as you noticed, in a lot of power losses in the wire).

You can either use an adjustable 12V power supply that you can plug in the outlet, or combine your 12V battery with a DC/DC converter. There are ready-to-buy modules with a potentiometer to adjust the voltage.

Comment: How exactly do I reduce the voltage of a battery(if even possible)? I'm using a 12v 12amp hour car battery

Comment: You are powering your lathe with a battery?

Comment: The motor, yes. Was I not supposed to?

Comment: You can do that, I just was not expecting it. I edited my answer with two possible solutions for you.

Comment: Ah a DC/DC converter might be the thing I'm looking for! Thank you I'll try it and see how it goes

Comment: I guess you are aware of it, but I will just mention it for good measure: Make sure that your DC/DC converter is capable of handling the current your motor needs ;)